# How to load model from network by Unity WebGL in run time？

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

How to load model from network by Unity WebGL in run time？
Any Code Samples?
I already get the bytes array of 'dae' files by UnityWebRequest,But how to load to prefab。
I'm trying to use Resources.Load() but it only support loacal path as parameter.
Please help me if anybody knows how to solve this. thanks a lot.

Comment: A prefab is usually already in its package. What exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: My appeal is request and load dae model to the scene by HTTP in unity webgl.